# latex and evince

Tags: latex, evince, sublime-text

When I compile a latex file with the text editor I use (Sublime text) it updates my pdf file in Evince and switches back correctly to my sublime. However, Evince tries to help me by indicating with a red box which part of the document has been updated. But this red box is quite poorly designed and usually covers the new parts of the document which I want to check if they are correct. Do you know if there is a setting in Evince where I can make it so that it no longer shows this annoying box?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a LaTex feature; more precise, a feature from the Hyperref package.

From [Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks/) on tex.stackexchange.com:

> With `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` you get active links in `\textcolor` (usually black) without a box around them.

I'm not aware of a feature in evince to change this. I assume evince simply follows the PDF standard here, and renders red boxes as included by hyperref.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because I think that it doesn't answer the question. It's about forward and backward search, not about hyperlinks. Have you tried your solution? It doesn't work for me.